# Redirecting the shell output to a file

Tags: java, shell, output, aix, verbose

I am working on AIX 6 where I am running a java command on a Korn Shell and I am trying to debug the class loading issue. I put -verbose:class to print the class loaded and then >>/home/user/log.log to get the console out put in a file. The log.log file is got created but its of zero size. File is not containing any information and all the verbose details are ripping through the screen in a flash.

```
/usr/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/java/bin/java -verbose:class -cp "XXXXX" com.ibm.XXXX >>/home/user/log.log
```

Comment: The -verbose output happens on standard error, so what you want is `2>>logfile`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try redirecting `stderr` also:

```
/usr/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/java/bin/java -verbose:class -cp "XXXXX" com.ibm.XXXX >>/home/user/log.log 2>&1
```

Your Java code might be writing on `stderr` that your command isn't redirecting.